# Does anyone know of a java2d text library?

Tags: java, text, java-2d

This is what I need in my game regarding text:

```
Word Wrap Support given a bounding box
Vertical and Horizontal alignment given a bounding box
```

Now, I've been reading about how to use TextLayout, and it seems possible to write all this myself but I'd prefer to think at a higher level. I just want a Label class with a signature like this:

```
public Label(String text, Alignment alignment, VAlignment vAlignment);
```

Does anyone know of an open source (non-gpl) library out there that makes text formatting simple?

Comment: Are you using custom paint() methods or Swing components?

Comment: I'm using java2d so I'm using custom paint() methods.

Comment: I think most graphics programs have simply created their own text rendering. For maximum control, you can implement your own version using String.split(), FontMetrics etc.

Comment: This isn't flexible enough for me. My game has a chatroom

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java2d to paint your game graphics, you should be able to use the the awt or swing text components to render your text. You could e.g. create a JLabel and call its paint und update methods manually in your render queue with your Graphics2D context.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("your text");
label.setLocation(0, 100); 
label.setSize(20, 100);
label.paint(g); // g is your Graphics2D context
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this official tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html
It contains everything you'll ever need for displaying text.
Or more simply use TextLayout, if you don't like reading=) ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html )

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with @Daniel's answer, I arrived to the following solution:

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel("your text");
    label.setSize(screen); //screen is a Dimension Object..
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.paint(g2d); // g is your Graphics2D context
```

Hope it helps...